# Cisco ASA 5510 ASDM 6.4 (2) unable to do port translation

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, pat

I have a situation, where I want to do port translation. For example I can acces my service outside ip:8081 that is forwaded to server:8080.

I should have a NAT rule option to add PAT like in this picture:

[image]

But I don't have option to add PAT:

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone will help me to achieve this situation. Externalip:port translated to internalip:port2